# Can not access Google Drive API with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I am trying to get data from google drive

I am using googleapis_auth package to make authentication
https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth

It shows me that error:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)

Notes:
1- I have service account credentials
2- google drive is enabled from google cloud platform

This is my credentials and authentication code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<File> _items = [];
  bool _loaded = false;

  var client = http.Client();
  List<String> scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'];

  var credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "",
    "private_key_id": "",
    "private_key": "",
    "client_email": "",
    "client_id": "",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": ""
  });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
                        credentials, scopes, client)
                    .then((AccessCredentials credentials) {
                  print(credentials.accessToken.data);
                  //client.close();
                });
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FilesPage(client: client)));
              },
              child: Text('Log In'))),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my function to get files from google drive:

```
class FilesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final client;

  const FilesPage({Key key, this.client}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FilesPageState createState() => _FilesPageState();
}

class _FilesPageState extends State<FilesPage> {
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
  List<File> _items = [];
  bool _loaded = false;

  Future<void> getFiles() async {
    print('*******************load files');
    print(widget.client);
    DriveApi driveApi = DriveApi(widget.client);
    var files = await driveApi.files
        .list(q: 'mimeType=\'application/vnd.google-apps.documents\'');
    print('$files');
    setState(() {
      _items = files.files;
      _loaded = true;
      print('*****set state');
    });
    print('${_items.length}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getFiles();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _items[index];
          print('Item name is ${item.name}');
          return Card(
            elevation: 0.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2)),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    item.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'Hello',
                          //formatter.format(item.createdDate),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                      Text(
                        KtList.from(item.owners).joinToString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SizedBox(height: 8.0);
        },
        itemCount: _items.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is caused by using a service account. Do not use a service account to bypass user credentials for services such as drive, calendar, sheets, etc.  More details here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority

Comment: @JohnHanley Good point sir, but what should I use ? The package asks for the service account credentials !!

Comment: To use your own account you can follow the [Google Drive Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java). If this is not enough, could you add more context about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @عبداللهلبيب read the link in my comment and use supported authentication methods. If the package does not support the supported methods, I would choose a different package.